# Firebase, how to use auth service with a node.js RESTapi backend

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm a full-stack java script developer.

I have a project, the front-end was developed using the vue.js.

Back-end is developing using node.js express framework. My back-end is a RESTapi as well.

Since my front-end UI design is finished, I created a fire-base project and hosted it. It was dead simple to host the front-end part.

My back-end doesn't have a authentication part yet. I want to try the fire-base auth service in this project.

Normal way how I would do authentication is like this.

1. Pass details to the back-end to create a user account.
2. Backend creates an user account.
3. Then after when the user trying to logging credentials are pass to back-end and release a token from the back-end
4. That token stores in the user's browser temporary memory and attached with each and every request he pass to the back-end.
5. Back-end verify the token and gives access to the resources.

That's the normal flow I know.

I can't understand how this normal flow alters when I use fire-base to do the auth part of the my project.

**HOW DO I ACHIEVE MY AUTH REQUIREMENT USING THE FIREBASE?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two cases.

**First**, you omit the user creation part from the backend and create user accounts in the frontend using firebase authentication. The documentation has everything to get you startet: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start E.g. when using email and password authentication:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

Login after that:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

Remember:

> A Firebase User has a fixed set of basic properties—a unique ID, a
>   primary email address, a name and a photo URL—stored in the project's
>   user database, that can be updated by the user (iOS, Android, web).
>   You cannot add other properties to the Firebase User object directly;
>   instead, you can store the additional properties in your Firebase
>   Realtime Database.

From https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users

**Second**, you can route user creation through your backend by using firebase-admin in nodejs to create user accounts. Login requests will go from the frontend directly to firebase (and not to your backend). So the backend is just for user creation/management.

Comment: Thinks I first created user and signed in.then that your send me the request to access  to a path. Before allow him to access that path I need to check the validity of his token. How do I do that?

Comment: Most of the things clear now. One question, I use sequlize ORM and MySQL db so I have to host my project in a different platform? or Can I host my this setup in the firebase?

Comment: @PathumSamararathna firebase hosting is for web apps and static content, you cannot deploy a mysql database using it. However you could replace your mysql setup with firebase firestore

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I have a clear idea about what's going here. =)